# Python: Clean Code and Performance on For Loops

Tags: python

I have problems to apply clean code principles to this code section.
In clean code principles is written, that a function should do one thing and do it well.
But in this case I do not know how to refractor this function according to those principles without decreasing performance.

```
    for netobject in netObjectList:
        for key, value in netobject.getObjectParams().items():
            if value.getValue() == '' and key is not 'comment':
                Errorhandler().error_on_pos(value.getRow(), value.getCol(), 
str(key) + ' is missing')
            else:
                #do syntax check on values in the dictionary
                 NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue(key, value)
```

A netobject is dictionary containing all its parameters.

So I know that this function does more than one thing. And I think it is quite hard to unittest this function.
But if I proof syntax and missing parameters separatley, I have to iterate twice over all network objects bundled in that neObjectList. But otherwise it is no clean code to check syntax and missing parameters in one function.

I very often have these inner conflicts, when I am writing code.
Do you have some tips or suggestions to fix these problems?

If you need more description for that code section, please let me know.
Errorhandler is just a way to print out my errors, if an missing parameter is found.
The function checkSyntaxOfValue(key, value) calls suiteable check methods depending on the key of the bundled parameters. I think there would be also a better solution to handle syntax checks. But I do not know.

Comment: don't do `key is not 'comment'` but `key != "comment"`. Strings interning may work ... or not.

Comment: Thank you I have changed it to your solution.

Comment: put the code execution inside the loop in a separate function: first for{function_1}, then inside function_1 you will have second loop{function_2}, then inside function_2, you will have the execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, your code IS "doing one thing": validating your `netobject`s values. The fact that the validation is done in two steps (first checking if there's a value where expected, then checking the value's 'syntax') is an implementation detail.

Now what can be questionned is whether checking for empty values is distinct from checking the value's syntax - ie if an empty value is not a valid syntax for a given key, shouldn't the check be a responsability of `NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue` ?

Also if for whatever reason you really do have to keep the tests (empty value / value syntax) distinct, you should probably encapsulate the emptyness test in a distinct function so you have the same level of abstraction for both tests, ie:

```
def checkForNotEmptyValue(key, value):
   if key == 'comment':
       # we don't care about empty values here
       return True
   if value.getValue() == '':
       Errorhandler().error_on_pos(
           value.getRow(), 
           value.getCol(), 
           '{} is missing'.format(key)
            )
       return False
   return True
```

and then

```
for netobject in netObjectList:
    for key, value in netobject.getObjectParams().items():
        if checkForNotEmptyValue(key, value): 
            NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue(key, value)
```

NB: this is just an example based on your code snippet and question - I don't have enough context to tell whether it's the "best" solution here.

As a last word: don't get over the top with "best practices" either. Writing clean code IS important, but "clean" is a relative notion, and trying to strictly follow all "golden rules" is downright impossible (specially since no one really agrees on those rules xD).

Actually, the point of "golden rules" etc is to make you aware of what problem you *might* have if you don't follow the rule - once you know, it's your responsability to decide when the rule applies and when it's doesn't. It's like raising children: at first you just forbid them to cross the road alone because they are too young to really understand the dangers. Once they are mature enough to get the point, the rule becomes useless.

Answer (score -1):

Let me comment on your code first:

```
for netobject in netObjectList:
    for key, value in netobject.getObjectParams().items():
        """
        Below you seem to be assuming that first item must have 'comment' as key?
        What if the key 'comment' actually exists? If you iterate like this you will be 
        Throwing errors until you iterate through all the items (and either hit the required key or not)
        """
        if value.getValue() == '' and key is not 'comment':
            Errorhandler().error_on_pos(value.getRow(), value.getCol(), str(key) + ' is missing') 
        else:  
            NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue(key, value)
```

So, I'd choose a different approach. If you definitely want to work with item having key 'comment' 
(and assuming here that your keys are unique - ie no multiple 'comment' keys in a single netobject object) you could do this instead:

```
for netobject in netObjectList:
    try:
        # try to get the value directly 
        # (of course you could use .keys() instead of .items() to evaluate existing keys first)
        value = netobject.getObjectParams()['comment']
        NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue('comment', value)
    except:
        # Due to KeyError we now know for sure that such key definitely doesn't exist
        # So we can handle the Exception, or throw your own such as:
        Errorhandler().error_on_pos(...)
```

This example will either throw you just one True (ie not false positive) error, or it will succeed with syntax check

EDIT:

Decided to illustrate with better example:

Here I'm first emulating your netobject

```
class netobject_class(object):
    def __init__(self, datadict):
        self.data = datadict

    def getObjectParams(self):
        return self.data

    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a netobject_class instance (hash=" + str(self.__hash__()) + ") containing a data Dict"
```

Now we create the netObjectList which contains 3 sample netobject_class instances. Note that second Dict has no 'comment' key.

```
netObjectList = [
    netobject_class({'comment': 'comment1'}),
    netobject_class({'somekey':'somevalue','somekey2':'somevalue2'}),  
    netobject_class({'comment': 'comment2'})
]
```

Now we run the code:

```
print("-" * 40)
for netobject in netObjectList:
    # print("Working with netobject: %s" % netobject)
    try:
        # try to get the value directly
        # (of course you could use .keys() instead of .items() to evaluate existing keys first)
        value = netobject.getObjectParams()['comment']
        print("****** value='%s' # aka comment" % value)
        #NValidator.checkSyntaxOfValue('comment', value)
    except Exception as e:
        # Due to KeyError we now know for sure that such key definitely doesn't exist
        # So we can handle the Exception, or throw your own such as:
        print('Error: key', str(e), 'does not exist! Skipping....')
    print("-" * 40)
```

And this produces:

```
----------------------------------------
****** value='comment1' # aka comment
----------------------------------------
Error: key 'comment' does not exist! Skipping....
----------------------------------------
****** value='comment2' # aka comment
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Where have you seen that the OP's code "assumes" that first item must have 'comment' as key" ??? This is just NOT what the code is doing, this test is applied to ALL the items

Comment: Oh I have to say that the comment is optional. The dictionary contains always the same keys and the length is always the same.

Comment: The if statement skip the comment key and print an error when a key is missing

Comment: sorry when a value is missing, not a key

Comment: ©bruno Take it easy. I assumed that, as I wouldn't decide to throw errors before I haven't even iterated through items...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Just out of curiosity which part of my example is unclean or fails to achieve the objective, is in-optimal, or otherwise worth a downvote?

Comment: @HarlyH. I already explained what is wrong with your answer, cf my above comment.